# How to connect websocket API with AWS Websocket API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, websocket

We have implemented WebSocket which is running on a ec2 machine and from public ip it is working fine.
We want to map this WebSocket path with API Gateway so that our public ip will not be visible to others and we can run through in the same manner in which we are running our other apis which is based on HTTP protocol.
But the problem is we don’t have any idea to map external WebSocket address with API Gateway.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can map the websocket endpoint using the http(s) protocol in your api gateway and enable session stickyness in your loadbalancer.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html